# jQuery: Change keyboard value when input

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Example: when I press key "A" on a keyboard, then the value will change to "S" and text box show up "S".

How can I do this with jQuery or Tinymce 4?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to check the `keyCode` in every `keypress` event. If the `keyCode` is the same with `A` then you need to change it to whatever string you want, for example: `S`.

```
<div>
    <label>Test:</label>
    <input type="text" id="test">
</div>

$("#test").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (97 == e.keyCode || 65 == e.keyCode) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newString = $("#test").val() + "S";
        $("#test").val(newString);
    }
});
```

`97` is the keycode for `a` and `65` is keycode for `A`.

`a` will not be shown in the box with `e.preventDefault();`

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctucL578/1/).