# change spaces entered in input field to underscore in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that should switch all spaces entered to a '_' in real time. Meaning when the user hits the spacebar in that input field a underscore is being displayed instead of a space. I am quite new to javascript/jquery so please don't judge my setTimeout-n00bidity to hard:

```
$( "#inputId" ).keydown(function (key){
    var code = key.keyCode || key.which;
    if( code == 32 ) { //Space key code
        $( this ).val(
            function( index, value ){
                return value.substr( 0, value.length - 1 );
        })
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "_");
            }, 10
        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may listen to the `input` event and then replace the spaces with underscores in the listener. This way, you don't need to have a timeout.

```js
$("#inputId").on('input', function(key) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(value.replace(/ /g, '_'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputId">
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I accept as answer even though I am more of a 4-spaces kind a guyd :P

Answer (score 4):

No jQuery, simple solution:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inputId");

input.oninput = function (e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(' ', '_');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keyup` event rather than `keydown`, and simply replace all spaces with `_`. The `keyup` event runs after the value has been modified based on what the user typed, so you don't need to check the `charCode`.

```
$("#inputId").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, oldval) {
        return oldval.replace(/ /g, '_');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Change value of key board input**
ex:

```
<div>
    <label>Test:</label>
    <input type="text" id="test">
</div>

$("#test").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (32 == e.keyCode) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newString = $("#test").val() + "_";
        $("#test").val(newString);
    }
});
```

Related: [jQuery: Change keyboard value when input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236831/jquery-change-keyboard-value-when-input)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#inputId" ).keyup(function (key){
    var code = key.keyCode || key.which;
    if( code == 32 ) { //Space key code        
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g,"_"));
    }
});
```